# firebase realtime database client is offline

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

when I'm search data in firebase database, I got this error messages. client is offline.
How can I solve?

//2022-01-16 21:42:34.589 29418-29624/com.lepetitprincess.pointcard I/RepoOperation: get for query /issuers/iyGGn9JHdpYGR0YEWXMxOMtTH0s1/account falling back to disk cache after error: Client is offline
//2022-01-16 21:42:34.813 29418-29418/com.lepetitprincess.pointcard E/firebase: Error getting data
//java.lang.Exception: Client is offline
//at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.lambda$get$1$com-google-firebase-database-connection-PersistentConnectionImpl(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:441)
//at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:8)
//at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
//at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
//at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
//at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
//at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
//at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: Have you tried checking the data if it exists or not? Attach your code so we can help you better.
if(database.snapshot.child("somthing").exist()){//TODO}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, i fixed it by creating the application class and changing the Persistence settings of database to enabled so:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Firebase.database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

and don't forget to set the application class in the manifest file:

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```